# azure point to site VPN - User Management

Tags: azure, vpn

The Point to Site VPN provided by Azure is great and allows me to build a relatively inexpensive "corporate" network for my small, all remote user business. The only issue that is stopping me is figuring out how to do individual user management during the off-boarding process. It appears that by using the pre-shared keys with no other authentication that the only way to off-board a employee and remove their VPN access would be to re-generate all the keys (root and client). Am I missing something, is there some other means to manage cutting access to a user that leaves the company?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: good question. don't know the definite answer, but I believe you would need to look into revoking the certificate.  just don't know how to do that with self-signed certs.  will keep an eye on this thread

Comment: As best I can tell you would have to delete the root key, regenerate a new one, add it to the Virtual Network, gen a new client cert and send it to all remaining users. Seems a bit cumbersome. I'll do some testing on that and see how it works. Hopefully MS will add an additional layer of authentication that could be centrally managed.

Comment: Genning and uploading new key didn't work. After doing so I couldn't connect. I deleted everything (VMs and VN) and rebuild everything using the new keys that had failed previously and it worked. I'm expecting a call from MS on this. More to come.

Comment: According to MS - at this time re-genning the keys is the only way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for other solutions.